# In a WiX installer how do you determine which features have been selected for installation?

Tags: wix, wix3

I am using WiX Toolset v3.11 and would like to find out the state of the features after the user has made selections by using a Selection Tree in the Custom dialog.

For example, I have this feature:

```
  <Feature Id="Miscellaneous" Title="Miscellaneous" Description="Stuff." Level="4" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <MergeRef Id="miscMM"/>
  </Feature>
```

How can I test if this features has been selected to be installed?

I am trying to set a property that will be used in the final dialog that will summarize the features that will be installed.

For the Next button that opens the Summary Dialog I have tried this:

```
  <Publish Property="INST_MISC" Value="Yes"><![CDATA[Miscellaneous <> "4"]]></Publish>
```

but it always evaluates to true regardless of the Selection Tree setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This ***seems*** to do what I want:

```
<Publish Property="INST_MISC" Value="Yes"><![CDATA[(&Miscellaneous AND &Miscellaneous=3)]]></Publish>
<Publish Property="INST_MISC" Value="No"><![CDATA[NOT &Miscellaneous OR (&Miscellaneous AND &Miscellaneous<>3)]]></Publish>
<Publish Property="INST_MISC" Value="When required"><![CDATA[(&Miscellaneous AND &Miscellaneous=1)]]></Publish>
```

Comment: That's it. Windows Installer condition syntax g is a little overboard on special characters to return all those states, but documentation is pretty clear about it